# Python, replacing characters in a string while preserving original string

Tags: python, python-3.x

More specifically:

Given a string and a non-empty word string, return a version of the original String where all chars have been replaced by pluses ("+"), except for appearances of the word string which are preserved unchanged.

```
def(base,word):
plusOut("12xy34", "xy") → "++xy++"
plusOut("12xy34", "1") → "1+++++"
plusOut("12xy34xyabcxy", "xy") → "++xy++xy+++xy"
```

My original thought was this:

```
def main():

    x = base.split(word)  
    y = ''.join(x)
    print(y.replace(y,'+')*len(y))
```

From here I have trouble reinserting the word back into the str in the correct places. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `str` is a builtin so you're already inviting problems by using that as a reference to something else. How do you envisage `print(y.replace(y,'+')*len(y))` working in your example?

Comment: Well I figured I would try to break down the problem into smaller problems first. That just replaces everything that isn't the target word with the '+', edited to replace str with another variable name

Comment: The first thing you're doing is splitting the string down into a list and immediately re-joining it. I think you perhaps want to apply your transforms on the list version, before you do `y = ''.join(x)`.

Comment: Would you be open to use a regex?  Something like: `def plusOut(word, mask): return re.sub(r'[^%s]' % mask, '+', word)`?

Comment: Unfortunately haven't learned regex yet, any solution without using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any string to `join` (instead of the empty string `''` like you have).

```
def plusOut(s, word):
    x = s.split(word)
    y = ['+' * len(z) for z in x]
    final = word.join(y)
    return final
```

Edit: I've removed the regex, but I'm keeping the function across multiple lines to more closely match your original code.

Comment: Why use a regex here?  Why not just `y = ['+'*len(z) for z in x]`?  Or putting the entire function into one line: `return word.join('+'*len(z) for z in s.split(word))`.

Comment: Simple and succinct! However we haven't learned regex yet, is there anyway to do this without using regex?

Comment: If I'm reading the list comprehension correctly is it saying: for every word in x, append '+'  len(z) times?

Comment: @RocketHazmat good suggestion; sometimes I just think of regexes first!

Comment: @CuriousStudent I've rewritten to remove the regex. Lemme know if you've got any questions about it. :)

Comment: @CuriousStudent: `x` will be a list of strings.  You are splitting your original string into a list based upon `'xy'` (instead of like a comma).  So, `len(z)` is the length of each section, or how many `'+'` to use.  Then you glue those sections back together with the `'xy'`.

Comment: @PierceDarragh how exactly is word joining with y? Does join automatically place the argument at the beginning and end of the word? Or I guess how does join know when to stop

Comment: `join` takes an iterable as an argument, and `y` is a list of strings (and lists are iterable). It inserts `word` in between each of the elements of the list you give it. So `'a'.join(['b', 'c'])` would return the string `'bac'`.

Comment: @PierceDarragh Do you happen to know why if you have     'abc.join['x','y','z']' the output is not xabcyabczabc?

Comment: @CuriousStudent The `'abc'` part is only inserted *between* the elements of the list; not after each of them.

Comment: @PierceDarragh Thank you so much for answering!

Comment: @CuriousStudent no problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

A regex is not required. We can solve this without any libraries, iterating through exactly once.

We want to iterate through the indices i of the string, yielding the word and jumping ahead by len(word) if the slice of len(word) starting at i matches the word, and by yielding '+' and incrementing by one otherwise.

```
def replace_chars_except_word(string, word):
    def generate_chars():
        i = 0  
        while i < len(string):
            if string[i:(i+len(word))] == word:
                i += len(word)
                yield word
            else:
                yield '+'
                i+= 1
    return ''.join(generate_chars())


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    test_string = 'stringabcdefg string11010string1'
    result = replace_chars_except_word(test_string, word = 'string')
    assert result == 'string++++++++string+++++string+'
```

I use an internal generator function to yield the strings, but you could use a buffer to replace the internal function. (This is slightly less memory efficient).

`buffer = []
if (condition)
    buffer.append(word)
else:
    buffer.append'+'
return ''.join(buffer)`